# Is there a way to modify this without JS or Jquery?

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

I found this image carousel [here](http://codepen.io/bonkalol/pen/uHfhB) I'm wondering if there is a way to make it not auto scroll but instead have navigation buttons, as well as make it responsive. Is there a way to do this but still keep it Css only?

```
<h1>css3 carousel</h1>

<div class="carousel">
<div class="holder">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x200" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/400x300" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x400" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/210x105" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x150" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x100" alt="" />
 </div>
</div>


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);

body {
font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Verdana;
background-color: #eee;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 48px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #222;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}

.carousel {
 width: 830px;
 height: 120px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 8px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 2px solid #999;
 box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;

   }

.holder {
 animation: carousel 25s linear infinite;
 white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: transform;

  &:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  }
 }

 @keyframes carousel {
   0% {
   transform: translateX(0);
 }

   50% {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   }

   100% {
  transform: translateX(0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: You won't make navigate buttons with only CSS. Responsiveness is definitely possible but I don't know what you want to achieve in that matter and what have you already tried.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not possible when regular sliders have navigation and [this](http://codepen.io/reannea/pen/egDGd) has navigation?
And by resposive, I mean fitting to all screens. So if I resize the page, the images and container itself respond to the page without adding a scrolling option like it does now.

Comment: Your example can have navigation because it's made for a set-in-stone number of elements (two in this case), for image gallery with unknown number of images it would be a pain/impossible to do in CSS and I'd consider it strongly unrecommended for production purposes (well, unless you just want to mess around like the author of this codepen). As for the carousel, you can simply add `max-width: 100%` to force it to resize.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your CSS slightly will add a basic hover functionality to start the slider form a stopped position.

```
.holder {
  animation: carousel 25s linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: transform;
  animation-play-state: paused;

  &:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
}
```

Making it responsive would be easy with 'media queries'.

But considering you want to make it responsive then you will need 'click events' to make it work on mobile (as mobile has no hover functionality). CSS can't do click events so you will need javascript or jQuery. But this should be fairly straight forward, you'll only be changing minor CSS with a simple click event. However considering the endless amount of free and basic carousel plugins out there, I would opt for one of them. What you have here seems to be a demonstration on CSS animations, and without some kind of javascript, you will always be limited when it comes to CSS animation control.